# How Long Can Prometheus Gauge Keep its Value

Tags: prometheus, micrometer

I want to use `Gauge` metrics along with various labels to record an app's start time, git commit and various other info.

I have an `ApplicationListener` that executes a block of code after the app starts(listens on app start event). So I set the gauge value there. The gauge won't be updated any more during the app's lifecycle until it restarts.

The problem is I cannot find that metric on grafana, it seems it doesn't exist. I wonder if it's because it's not updated at the minimum required frequency? I'm using Java micrometer library to publish prometheus metrics.

Comment: From Prometheus' point, metric will be there as long as it is exposed and scraped (+5 minutes if your app died or stopped responding for other reasons).

Comment: Your approach is reasonable and used by Prometheus' own exporters: notice `go_info` on this node_exporter [metrics page](https://node.demo.do.prometheus.io/metrics). So you should not have problem with it, if exposition is done correctly.

Comment: @markalex I wonder how can I display only the latest value if prometheus keeps all the metric values? For e.g `app_info{application, git} start_ts`, the git label gets updated every time there's a new release, but all the stale values would still linger.

Comment: Prometheus only keeps scraped metrics. If you stop exposing metrics with older labels, Prometheus will stop returning them (maybe +5 minutes as mentioned before, and if you don't use Pushgateway)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are misusing the `Gauge`, please make sure you read the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges) first, here's an example for what you are trying to do:

```java
Gauge.builder("jvm.info", () -> 1L)
        .tags("version", System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"))
        .register(registry);
```

Here's a concrete example in [JvmInfoMetrics](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/3f23cdded2de3271f1c449e7a5e9280a158398b4/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmInfoMetrics.java)